Get the VMware datastore with the most free space with Ansible
I'm trying to get the VMware datastore with the most free space and later use its URL to create a storage class in a Kubernetes cluster.
I'm getting the info using vmware_datastore_info module, as shown below:
--- 
- name: Gather info from ESXi datacenter
  hosts: localhost 
  gather_facts: false 
 
  tasks: 
  - name: Gather info from ESXi datastore 
    vmware_datastore_info: 
      hostname: '{{ vcenter_server }}' 
      username: '{{ username }}' 
      password: '{{ password }}' 
      datacenter_name: '{{ datacenter_name }}' 
      validate_certs: false 
    delegate_to: localhost 
    register: info 

  - debug: var=info.datastores


Sample info.datastores result
{
    "msg": [
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 5156108238848,
            "datastore_cluster": "DDA_SPIT_013_002",
            "freeSpace": 5154511257600,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "LIT013_078",
            "provisioned": 1596981248,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 0,
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e55997-3946cc08-ce62-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 5156108238848,
            "datastore_cluster": "DDA_SPIT_013_002",
            "freeSpace": 5154341388288,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "LIT013_075",
            "provisioned": 11265900544,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 9499049984,
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e5595d-02d66360-bf73-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 5156108238848,
            "datastore_cluster": "DDA_SPIT_013_002",
            "freeSpace": 5154511257600,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "LIT013_077",
            "provisioned": 1596981248,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 0,
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e55986-d2d1286a-5c00-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 5156108238848,
            "datastore_cluster": "DDA_SPIT_013_002",
            "freeSpace": 5154079244288,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "LIT013_067",
            "provisioned": 2943352832,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 914358272,
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/60743b62-a519d76c-1d48-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 5156108238848,
            "datastore_cluster": "DDA_SPIT_013_002",
            "freeSpace": 5154511257600,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "LIT013_074",
            "provisioned": 1596981248,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 0,
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e5594a-07107de8-1823-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 5156108238848,
            "datastore_cluster": "DDA_SPIT_013_002",
            "freeSpace": 5154511257600,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "LIT013_072",
            "provisioned": 1596981248,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 0,
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e5591a-1ed49f04-2a09-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 5156108238848,
            "datastore_cluster": "DDA_SPIT_013_002",
            "freeSpace": 4399479914496,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "LIT013_071",
            "provisioned": 1383218544640,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 626590220288,
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e558fc-6a916ba4-82d3-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "accessible": true,
            "capacity": 5156108238848,
            "datastore_cluster": "CZCHO_SPIT_013_002",
            "freeSpace": 3060709457920,
            "maintenanceMode": "normal",
            "multipleHostAccess": true,
            "name": "LIT013_070",
            "provisioned": 2428559687680,
            "type": "VMFS",
            "uncommitted": 333160906752,
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/6346c446-6219e6bc-f0a7-9440c96b1102/"
        }
    ]
}

How can I get only one datastores.url from this result?

A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    info:
      datastores: [
        {
            "freeSpace": 5154511257600,
            "name": "LIT013_078",
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e55997-3946cc08-ce62-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "freeSpace": 5154341388288,
            "name": "LIT013_075",
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e5595d-02d66360-bf73-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "freeSpace": 5154511257600,
            "name": "LIT013_077",
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e55986-d2d1286a-5c00-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "freeSpace": 5154079244288,
            "name": "LIT013_067",
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/60743b62-a519d76c-1d48-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "freeSpace": 5154511257600,
            "name": "LIT013_074",
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e5594a-07107de8-1823-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "freeSpace": 5154511257600,
            "name": "LIT013_072",
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e5591a-1ed49f04-2a09-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "freeSpace": 4399479914496,
            "name": "LIT013_071",
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e558fc-6a916ba4-82d3-9440c96b1102/"
        },
        {
            "freeSpace": 3060709457920,
            "name": "LIT013_070",
            "url": "ds:///vmfs/volumes/6346c446-6219e6bc-f0a7-9440c96b1102/"
        }
      ]

  tasks:

    - name: This is
      debug:
        msg: "{{ info.datastores | type_debug }}"

    - name: with elements of
      debug:
        msg: "{{ info.datastores | first | type_debug }}"

show
TASK [This is] ***************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: list

TASK [with elements of] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: dict

that you have a list of dictionaries. So one approach could be simply extract the key tied to min/max value in a list of multiple dictionaries, means sort it and use the last maximum value / element.
    - name: and max entry
      debug:
        msg: "{{ info.datastores | sort(attribute='freeSpace') | last }}"

with
TASK [and max entry] *******************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    freeSpace: 5154511257600
    name: LIT013_072
    url: ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e5591a-1ed49f04-2a09-9440c96b1102/

To get the URL only use in example
"{{ (info.datastores | sort(attribute='freeSpace') | last).url }}"

Further Reading

How to work with a list of dictionaries in Ansible


You can use the max filter from Jinja right away on a list of dictionaries.
You just have to provide the attribute you want the max to apply on, when dealing with dictionaries:

Parameters:

case_sensitive – Treat upper and lower case strings as distinct.
attribute – Get the object with the max value of this attribute.


Source: max filter documentation
So, for your specific use case:
- name: Get the datastore URL with the most space
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ (info.datastores | max(attribute='freeSpace')).url }}"

Which would yield:
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: ds:///vmfs/volumes/64e55997-3946cc08-ce62-9440c96b1102/

